# Is it possible to add transparency to jpg in Java and Android

Tags: java, android

I want to load some images to the cloud, but I want to add some protections when someone views the photos and saves the images; they will not see anything because of the transparency.

would the code be common for Java and Android?  I would like to prototype it in Java first.

I have found some code that combines two files.  One file is my main file the other is a transparent file.  The combined file does not have a transparent overlay.

Do I need to use an image drawing order?
http://www.developer.nokia.com/document/Java_Developers_Library_v2/GUID-D3E35E6F-0C45-48ED-B09D-F716E14C1C02/javax/microedition/amms/control/imageeffect/OverlayControl.html

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("rose.jpg"));
    BufferedImage overlay = ImageIO.read(new File("myimg1.gif"));


    // create the new image, canvas size is the max. of both image sizes
    int w = Math.max(image.getWidth(), overlay.getWidth());
    int h = Math.max(image.getHeight(), overlay.getHeight());
    BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // paint both images, preserving the alpha channels
    Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, null);

    // Save as new image
    ImageIO.write(combined, "PNG", new File("combined.png"));
```

Comment: Add code to combine two photos but, does anybody know how to put the transparent image over the main image.  What I have does not work.  I would like it when the user sees the photo on the web then tries to do a "save as" the image they save would be the transparent and the image is useless to them.  This would be mainly for an android application.  Could I disable the saving and copying features in the browsers was another idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work.  If they can see the image, they can copy it, one way or another.  A solution to consider is providing watermarked thumbnails at no charge, then only offering the full resolution image for a fee.  However, they can still copy the full resolution image once they pay.

Comment: I can not prevent a person from taking a screen shot on the desktop but on android I want to prevent the user from saving it to the to the sd card.  One person told me if I do a clear tansparent overlay, when they save it; it does not show anything.  Is this possible.

Comment: a better explanation place a transparent image in front of the main image.  Anyone saving the image will be saving the transparent image and not the background one.  I will have protection in place when the image is downloaded the link will be deleted. so the user can not go back to try to take image capture.

Comment: @user1024882, there are still many ways they could get around this, including running the app in an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually put a trans image as an overlay to the orginial image, that will 
Protect from download, I think this is usually done by the server side aka your cloud
I know from some websites that they use some kind of an overlay such as yours
And the browser can't see the image below so you can't download.

I actually didn't understand how you implementing this - the image is opened in the browser?

Just a wild though, you can also cut the image into pieces like a jigsaw puzzle
The device won't have problems connecting it togther but when you download you'll
Download only "one piece of the puzzle" :-P